# change mySQL localTime to current time

Tags: java, mysql, database, time, timezone

I'm from Egypt and my time is +2 GMT , but my on-line server is on -5 GMT

so when calling some queries fro database to get time for 2 AM ! I got the data from Yesterday not for today

so I'm asking how to fix such problem using mySQL statement or Java code ?

for example when I called :

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())
```

It getting right value 3 , but if I called it on 3 AM local Time here in Egypt (1 GMT) it get it 2 ! .

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle time within a database is to always store the "UTC" time (even if you have to convert from local time when storing a timestamp). Then, when you retrieve the time you convert it to the "local time" of the client (browser usually in today's modern world) by applying the locale information.

If you use this process, you eliminate having to know where your server is located (and with hosting providers sometimes in locations you do not know ...).

Comment: it stored as UTC , but i insert time and get time from online server not from local device

Comment: then should convert time first to check if my current time here in egypt is == time in database table then do the code